# Using latitude and longitude to pin point a location in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I wrote a script to add maps to my website. It is as follows:

```
<script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9583182, 77.6398512),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

**`HTML code:`**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map">
</div>
```

**`css:`**

```
 #map{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

I added this code for pin pointing a location:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            //give latitude and long
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("12.9583182", "77.6398512");
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Bangalore" 
        });
```

But when I used that code, map on my page disappeared. How can I make it to work?

Comment: You're creating two maps, remove `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);` from your pin snippet

Comment: Cool, that worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating map two time on same div that's why its happening just change your code as below:

```
function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9583182, 77.6398512),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("12.9583182", "77.6398512");
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Bangalore" 
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

there is no need to add `var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);`
second time